# How to get the Request form for approval used in the template "Content Scheduler with approvals"?

Tags: sharepoint-online

When you choose the Sharepoint template "Content Scheduler with approvals". And click on the button  in the column ApprovalStatus then a form appears showing below. Its a approval request form. Where does this comes from. Is that a form from Microsoft Forms. How can i get this request form?

[image]

In the Json from the column ApprovalStatus it's called like this:

```
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "openApprovalDialog"
  }
```

Is it possbile for me to get also this request form in my own sharepoint list?

Gr. P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this great [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLVqBUG_Ls8) of Reza Dorrani about the feature **Content Scheduler with approvals**.

It's not a **Microsoft Forms** but a custom form with no ability to edit it. It relies on the **Approval** module of Power Platform.
In Microsoft Teams, you can add the `Approval` application to manage approvals you sent or received.

Internally, when you create a list with approvals, two new fields are created: `_ApprovalStatus` with a number (1, 2, 3 depending of the status and a custom JSON formatting to add a button to open the popup with the form) and `_ApprovalAssignedTo`.

According to the [official documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/approvals-in-lists-2bd0954d-5797-4be3-b78a-846f26338e17), only lists created with the built-in template can use the approval feature:

> **Modern approvals is not available on lists that were not created from
> the "Content scheduler with approvals" and "Travel requests with
> approvals" templates.**

So, you cannot add it on a custom list. Even if you try to create the same two fields with the same custom formatting on a custom list, it will not work. But maybe someday!

[image: custom JSON formatting]